# Why Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder must be prototype for JSON and XML Jackson converters?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am working with `Spring Framework` version *4.3.6.*

The application is based in a web environment and with support for *Rest*. Here `XML` and `JSON` is supported.

I work with **Jackson**. It through the classes:

- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`
- `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`

For them I use for a common configuration the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` class.

Now, I am confused with the following behaviour:

**Alpha**

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build());
    converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().createXmlMapper(true).build());
    converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//TODO re test
    builder.serializerByType(Date.class, new JsonSerializerForDate());
    builder.deserializerByType(Date.class, new JsonDeserializerForDate());
    return builder;
}
```

Here some points:

- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` uses `converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build())`
- `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` uses `converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().createXmlMapper(true).build())`
- Therefore both uses the same *Singleton* `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` object.

With this approach many test methods fails. Therefore I can have the following situation:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /personas
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = ....
           Method = public com.manuel....

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = <collection>
  <item>
    <id>087</id>
    <nombre>Leonardo</nombre>
    <apellido>Jordan</apellido>
  </item>
  ....
</collection>
```

How you can see for this `GET` the `Accept` value is `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and for the reply `Content-Type` is `application/json;charset=UTF-8` but *really* the body is in XML.

Just how an experiment I did the following:

**Beta**

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForJson().build());
    converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForXml().createXmlMapper(true).build());
    converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForJson(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//TODO re test
    builder.serializerByType(Date.class, new JsonSerializerForDate());
    builder.deserializerByType(Date.class, new JsonDeserializerForDate());
    return builder;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForXml(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//TODO re test
    builder.serializerByType(Date.class, new JsonSerializerForDate());
    builder.deserializerByType(Date.class, new JsonDeserializerForDate());
    return builder;
}
```

Works. Observe for these two `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` classes their configuration are the same, or in other words the `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForXml()` and `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderForJson()` methods have the same content.

**Delta**

Therefore from **Alpha**

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(){
```

**Note** I had this problem even with the following version:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return builder;
}
```

I did a research in the javadoc/API [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) and even in the Reference documentation, where there appears in some way an example similar than my code in the [22.16.12 Message Converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-message-converters) section. And there is no some indication about this `prototype` case.

Therefore: Why Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder must be prototype for JSON and XML Jackson converters?